# kill process with htop

Tags: htop

Sometimes I need to kill a process and for that purpose I enter `htop`, search (`/`) for some string and then intend to kill the associated process.

The problem is that usually the processes are in motion (due to new processes being added and attributes changing) - so by the time I pressed F9 and went on with "killing" the process the selected process is already a different one.

Is there a way to handle this?

The reason why I use htop is of course b/c I sometimes have to guess which is the right process to get rid of and just a string is not sufficient for identification.

Comment: I don't know if you can/have changed the update interval, but with the default one you at least could take care of pressing <kbd>F9</kbd> in the middle of that interval after you checked to have remained on the same process.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is possible to tag (and untag) a process with [space]. To the tagged process(es) the kill signal will be sent.

Answer (score 49):

After executing `sudo htop`, just use the arrow keys to select the process you want to remove and then press either `F9` or `k` then select which signal you want to send in the list (using the arrow keys) and press `enter`.

If you just to ask "politely" a process to quit use `3 SIGQUIT`.

If you want to make sure the process quits use `9 SIGKILL`.

Comment: The key is to use `sudo` for commands running as root. If you just run `htop`, it won't always close processes.

Comment: `SIGTERM` is what I usually go for

Answer (score 6):

use `htop` and note down the PID of the process.
Exit by entering `q`

then enter the command :

```
kill PID
```

If it is owned by the root, then :

```
sudo kill PID
```

Hope this'll help you ....

Answer (score 3):

First, press <kbd>F6</kbd> which is the "sort by" option.

Then, under the "sort by" category on the left, select option PID and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This should give you a more stable output.

Next, to locate a process, press <kbd>F3</kbd> to search, type in the search, and then press <kbd>F3</kbd> again to scroll through search results.

When the process is highlighted, press <kbd>F9</kbd> ***two times quickly*** and then press <kbd>9</kbd> and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to kill the process.