# Random Freezing with ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, gui, freeze, syslog

Installed ubuntu 14.04 and the system freezes at least once a day at what seems to be random times.

By Freezing I mean the mouse keyboard and screen won't react at all. 
This will happen no matter if the system is being , or it is idle with lockscreen on.

I have been having to hold the power button to my dektop (powerwash) in order to restart every time.

In my log var/logs/syslog it looks like there were processes running even after the screen froze. Considering what tasks were completed I believe the system froze last somewhere between 11 and 12. 12:50 is when I restarted the desktop.

If anyone can see the problem in my syslog or tell me where else to look it would be a great help. I don't even know where to begin.

```
    Mar  8 09:43:00 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4315.744847] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:50]
Mar  8 09:43:00 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4315.761520] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:51]
Mar  8 09:43:00 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4315.779039] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:52]
Mar  8 09:43:00 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4315.795394] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:53]
Mar  8 09:43:00 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4316.147743] [drm:intel_crtc_cursor_set_obj] cursor off
Mar  8 09:43:00 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4316.147759] [drm:g4x_check_srwm] SR watermark: display plane 51, cursor 2
Mar  8 09:43:00 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4316.147765] [drm:g4x_check_srwm] SR watermark: display plane 100, cursor 2
Mar  8 09:43:00 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4316.147771] [drm:valleyview_update_wm] Setting FIFO watermarks - A: plane=150, cursor=2, B: plane=2, cursor=2, SR: plane=51, cursor=2
Mar  8 09:43:00 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4316.147778] [drm:intel_set_memory_cxsr] memory self-refresh is enabled
Mar  8 09:43:01 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4316.427894] [drm:g4x_check_srwm] SR watermark: display plane 51, cursor 6
Mar  8 09:43:01 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4316.427905] [drm:g4x_check_srwm] SR watermark: display plane 100, cursor 10
Mar  8 09:43:01 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4316.427911] [drm:valleyview_update_wm] Setting FIFO watermarks - A: plane=150, cursor=6, B: plane=2, cursor=2, SR: plane=51, cursor=10
Mar  8 09:43:01 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4316.427919] [drm:intel_set_memory_cxsr] memory self-refresh is enabled
Mar  8 09:43:02 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4317.463828] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:54]
Mar  8 09:43:02 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4317.481212] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:55]
Mar  8 09:43:02 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4317.497587] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:56]
Mar  8 09:43:02 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4317.684299] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:57]
Mar  8 09:43:02 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4317.897821] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:58]
Mar  8 09:43:02 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4317.913903] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:59]
Mar  8 09:43:02 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4317.931722] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:60]
Mar  8 09:43:02 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4317.949703] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:61]
Mar  8 09:43:07 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4322.292837] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:37]
Mar  8 09:43:09 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4325.078441] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:45]
Mar  8 09:43:09 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4325.096236] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:49]
Mar  8 09:43:09 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4325.113447] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:50]
Mar  8 09:43:10 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4325.214863] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:51]
Mar  8 09:43:10 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4325.416992] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:52]
Mar  8 09:43:12 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4327.273145] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:53]
Mar  8 09:43:12 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4327.289811] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:54]
Mar  8 09:43:12 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4327.306292] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:55]
Mar  8 09:43:12 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4327.323071] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:56]
Mar  8 09:43:12 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4327.340752] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:57]
Mar  8 09:43:12 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4327.358048] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:58]
Mar  8 09:43:12 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4327.374379] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:59]
Mar  8 09:43:12 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4327.394037] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:60]
Mar  8 09:43:12 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4327.410758] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:61]
Mar  8 09:43:12 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4327.427707] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:62]
Mar  8 09:43:12 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4327.443585] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:63]
Mar  8 09:43:12 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4327.460723] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:64]
Mar  8 09:43:12 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4327.553663] [drm:intel_crtc_cursor_set_obj] cursor off
Mar  8 09:43:12 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4327.553676] [drm:g4x_check_srwm] SR watermark: display plane 51, cursor 2
Mar  8 09:43:12 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4327.553679] [drm:g4x_check_srwm] SR watermark: display plane 100, cursor 2
Mar  8 09:43:12 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4327.553682] [drm:valleyview_update_wm] Setting FIFO watermarks - A: plane=150, cursor=2, B: plane=2, cursor=2, SR: plane=51, cursor=2
Mar  8 09:43:12 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4327.553687] [drm:intel_set_memory_cxsr] memory self-refresh is enabled
Mar  8 09:43:17 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4332.315950] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:37]
Mar  8 09:43:21 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4336.605457] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:45]
Mar  8 09:43:27 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4343.134308] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:37]
Mar  8 09:43:28 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4343.217508] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:46]
Mar  8 09:43:28 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4343.237526] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:47]
Mar  8 09:43:28 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4343.404311] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:48]
Mar  8 09:43:39 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4354.223073] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:37]
Mar  8 09:43:46 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4361.683700] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:46]
Mar  8 09:43:47 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4363.222697] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:45]
Mar  8 09:43:52 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4367.492614] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:47]
Mar  8 09:43:58 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4373.658374] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:45]
Mar  8 09:44:00 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4375.443599] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:46]
Mar  8 09:44:09 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4384.694340] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:45]
Mar  8 09:44:09 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4384.710745] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:47]
Mar  8 09:44:22 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4397.637399] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:37]
Mar  8 09:44:25 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4400.741757] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:45]
Mar  8 09:44:27 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4402.726987] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:37]
Mar  8 09:44:27 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4402.744098] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:45]
Mar  8 09:44:37 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4413.249817] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:45]
Mar  8 09:44:47 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4422.968763] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:37]
Mar  8 09:44:54 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4430.001168] [drm:g4x_check_srwm] SR watermark: display plane 51, cursor 6
Mar  8 09:44:54 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4430.001173] [drm:g4x_check_srwm] SR watermark: display plane 100, cursor 10
Mar  8 09:44:54 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4430.001177] [drm:valleyview_update_wm] Setting FIFO watermarks - A: plane=150, cursor=6, B: plane=2, cursor=2, SR: plane=51, cursor=10
Mar  8 09:44:54 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4430.001182] [drm:intel_set_memory_cxsr] memory self-refresh is enabled
Mar  8 09:44:54 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4430.042514] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:48]
Mar  8 09:44:54 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4430.058329] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:49]
Mar  8 09:44:54 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4430.075287] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:50]
Mar  8 09:44:54 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4430.092659] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:51]
Mar  8 09:44:54 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4430.109440] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:52]
Mar  8 09:44:54 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4430.125369] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:53]
Mar  8 09:44:54 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4430.142871] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:54]
Mar  8 09:44:54 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4430.159298] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:55]
Mar  8 09:44:54 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4430.169468] [drm:intel_crtc_cursor_set_obj] cursor off
Mar  8 09:44:54 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4430.169479] [drm:g4x_check_srwm] SR watermark: display plane 51, cursor 2
Mar  8 09:44:54 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4430.169483] [drm:g4x_check_srwm] SR watermark: display plane 100, cursor 2
Mar  8 09:44:54 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4430.169486] [drm:valleyview_update_wm] Setting FIFO watermarks - A: plane=150, cursor=2, B: plane=2, cursor=2, SR: plane=51, cursor=2
Mar  8 09:44:54 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4430.169490] [drm:intel_set_memory_cxsr] memory self-refresh is enabled
Mar  8 09:44:54 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4430.175327] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:46]
Mar  8 09:44:54 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4430.192360] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:56]
Mar  8 09:44:54 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4430.209190] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:57]
Mar  8 09:44:54 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4430.226080] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:58]
Mar  8 09:44:54 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4430.242318] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:59]
Mar  8 09:44:54 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4430.258232] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:60]
Mar  8 09:44:54 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4430.274703] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:61]
Mar  8 09:44:54 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4430.291413] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:62]
Mar  8 09:44:54 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4430.308201] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:63]
Mar  8 09:44:54 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4430.327979] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:64]
Mar  8 09:44:54 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4430.345819] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:65]
Mar  8 09:44:54 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4430.369626] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:66]
Mar  8 09:44:55 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4431.251777] [drm:g4x_check_srwm] SR watermark: display plane 51, cursor 6
Mar  8 09:44:55 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4431.251787] [drm:g4x_check_srwm] SR watermark: display plane 100, cursor 10
Mar  8 09:44:55 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4431.251794] [drm:valleyview_update_wm] Setting FIFO watermarks - A: plane=150, cursor=6, B: plane=2, cursor=2, SR: plane=51, cursor=10
Mar  8 09:44:55 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4431.251801] [drm:intel_set_memory_cxsr] memory self-refresh is enabled
Mar  8 09:44:57 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4432.768173] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:37]
Mar  8 09:44:57 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4433.028731] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:45]
Mar  8 09:44:57 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4433.045945] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:46]
Mar  8 09:44:59 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4435.115462] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:47]
Mar  8 09:44:59 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4435.132120] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:48]
Mar  8 09:44:59 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4435.151558] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:49]
Mar  8 09:44:59 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4435.165321] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:50]
Mar  8 09:44:59 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4435.181317] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:51]
Mar  8 09:44:59 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4435.198153] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2] [FB:52]
Mar  8 09:45:17 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4453.039454] [drm:i915_gem_open] 
Mar  8 09:45:18 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4453.612393] [drm:i915_gem_context_create_ioctl] HW context 1 created
Mar  8 09:45:18 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4453.616257] [drm:i915_gem_context_destroy_ioctl] HW context 1 destroyed
Mar  8 09:45:21 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4456.925566] [drm:intel_crtc_cursor_set_obj] cursor off
Mar  8 09:45:21 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4456.925578] [drm:g4x_check_srwm] SR watermark: display plane 51, cursor 2
Mar  8 09:45:21 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4456.925582] [drm:g4x_check_srwm] SR watermark: display plane 100, cursor 2
Mar  8 09:45:21 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4456.925585] [drm:valleyview_update_wm] Setting FIFO watermarks - A: plane=150, cursor=2, B: plane=2, cursor=2, SR: plane=51, cursor=2
Mar  8 09:45:21 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4456.925589] [drm:intel_set_memory_cxsr] memory self-refresh is enabled
Mar  8 09:45:21 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4457.133981] [drm:g4x_check_srwm] SR watermark: display plane 51, cursor 6
Mar  8 09:45:21 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4457.133988] [drm:g4x_check_srwm] SR watermark: display plane 100, cursor 10
Mar  8 09:45:21 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4457.133992] [drm:valleyview_update_wm] Setting FIFO watermarks - A: plane=150, cursor=6, B: plane=2, cursor=2, SR: plane=51, cursor=10
Mar  8 09:45:21 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4457.133997] [drm:intel_set_memory_cxsr] memory self-refresh is enabled
Mar  8 09:49:53 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4729.068579] [drm:i915_gem_open] 
Mar  8 09:49:53 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4729.165197] [drm:i915_gem_context_create_ioctl] HW context 1 created
Mar  8 09:49:53 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4729.172257] [drm:i915_gem_context_destroy_ioctl] HW context 1 destroyed
Mar  8 09:51:17 ray-desktop AptDaemon: INFO: Quitting due to inactivity
Mar  8 09:51:17 ray-desktop AptDaemon: INFO: Quitting was requested
Mar  8 09:53:07 ray-desktop kernel: [ 4924.026964] perf interrupt took too long (4388 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 50000
Mar  8 10:04:03 ray-desktop kernel: [ 5580.985453] [drm:intel_crtc_cursor_set_obj] cursor off
Mar  8 10:04:03 ray-desktop kernel: [ 5580.985469] [drm:g4x_check_srwm] SR watermark: display plane 51, cursor 2
Mar  8 10:04:03 ray-desktop kernel: [ 5580.985475] [drm:g4x_check_srwm] SR watermark: display plane 100, cursor 2
Mar  8 10:04:03 ray-desktop kernel: [ 5580.985481] [drm:valleyview_update_wm] Setting FIFO watermarks - A: plane=150, cursor=2, B: plane=2, cursor=2, SR: plane=51, cursor=2
Mar  8 10:04:03 ray-desktop kernel: [ 5580.985489] [drm:intel_set_memory_cxsr] memory self-refresh is enabled
Mar  8 10:09:02 ray-desktop CRON[4528]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -x /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean /var/lib/php5 $(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime))
Mar  8 10:17:01 ray-desktop CRON[4544]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Mar  8 10:39:01 ray-desktop CRON[4564]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -x /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean /var/lib/php5 $(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime))
Mar  8 10:51:27 ray-desktop kernel: [ 8431.177109] [drm:g4x_check_srwm] SR watermark: display plane 51, cursor 6
Mar  8 10:51:27 ray-desktop kernel: [ 8431.177118] [drm:g4x_check_srwm] SR watermark: display plane 100, cursor 10
Mar  8 10:51:27 ray-desktop kernel: [ 8431.177125] [drm:valleyview_update_wm] Setting FIFO watermarks - A: plane=150, cursor=6, B: plane=2, cursor=2, SR: plane=51, cursor=10
Mar  8 10:51:27 ray-desktop kernel: [ 8431.177133] [drm:intel_set_memory_cxsr] memory self-refresh is enabled
Mar  8 10:51:28 ray-desktop kernel: [ 8431.179894] [drm:intel_set_memory_cxsr] memory self-refresh is disabled
Mar  8 10:51:28 ray-desktop kernel: [ 8431.214810] [drm:intel_set_memory_cxsr] memory self-refresh is disabled
Mar  8 10:51:28 ray-desktop kernel: [ 8431.214822] [drm:valleyview_update_wm] Setting FIFO watermarks - A: plane=2, cursor=2, B: plane=2, cursor=2, SR: plane=0, cursor=0
Mar  8 10:51:28 ray-desktop kernel: [ 8431.214831] [drm:intel_display_power_put] disabling dpio-common
Mar  8 10:51:28 ray-desktop kernel: [ 8431.238785] [drm:intel_display_power_put] disabling display
Mar  8 10:51:28 ray-desktop kernel: [ 8431.255040] [drm:check_encoder_state] [ENCODER:29:DAC-29]
Mar  8 10:51:28 ray-desktop kernel: [ 8431.255050] [drm:check_encoder_state] [ENCODER:30:TMDS-30]
Mar  8 10:51:28 ray-desktop kernel: [ 8431.255055] [drm:check_encoder_state] [ENCODER:35:TMDS-35]
Mar  8 10:51:28 ray-desktop kernel: [ 8431.255060] [drm:check_crtc_state] [CRTC:20]
Mar  8 10:51:28 ray-desktop kernel: [ 8431.255066] [drm:check_crtc_state] [CRTC:25]
Mar  8 10:51:28 ray-desktop kernel: [ 8431.255108] [drm:drm_mode_setcrtc] [CRTC:20]
Mar  8 10:51:28 ray-desktop kernel: [ 8431.255114] [drm:intel_crtc_set_config] [CRTC:20] [NOFB]
Mar  8 10:51:28 ray-desktop kernel: [ 8431.255122] [drm:intel_set_config_compute_mode_changes] computed changes for [CRTC:20], mode_changed=1, fb_changed=0
Mar  8 10:51:28 ray-desktop kernel: [ 8431.255127] [drm:intel_modeset_stage_output_state] [CONNECTOR:28:VGA-1] to [NOCRTC]
Mar  8 10:51:28 ray-desktop kernel: [ 8431.255132] [drm:intel_modeset_stage_output_state] encoder changed, full mode switch
Mar  8 10:51:28 ray-desktop kernel: [ 8431.255136] [drm:intel_modeset_stage_output_state] crtc changed, full mode switch
Mar  8 10:51:28 ray-desktop kernel: [ 8431.255141] [drm:intel_modeset_stage_output_state] crtc disabled, full mode switch
Mar  8 10:51:28 ray-desktop kernel: [ 8431.255147] [drm:intel_modeset_affected_pipes] set mode pipe masks: modeset: 0, prepare: 0, disable: 1
Mar  8 10:51:28 ray-desktop kernel: [ 8431.255159] [drm:intel_display_power_get] enabling display
Mar  8 10:51:28 ray-desktop kernel: [ 8431.279019] [drm:i915_redisable_vga_power_on] Something enabled VGA plane, disabling it
Mar  8 10:51:28 ray-desktop kernel: [ 8431.311005] [drm:vlv_update_cdclk] Current CD clock rate: 200000 kHz
Mar  8 10:51:28 ray-desktop kernel: [ 8431.311016] [drm:intel_display_power_put] disabling display
Mar  8 10:51:28 ray-desktop kernel: [ 8431.334986] [drm:check_encoder_state] [ENCODER:29:DAC-29]
Mar  8 10:51:28 ray-desktop kernel: [ 8431.334995] [drm:check_encoder_state] [ENCODER:30:TMDS-30]
Mar  8 10:51:28 ray-desktop kernel: [ 8431.335001] [drm:check_encoder_state] [ENCODER:35:TMDS-35]
Mar  8 10:51:28 ray-desktop kernel: [ 8431.335006] [drm:check_crtc_state] [CRTC:20]
Mar  8 10:51:28 ray-desktop kernel: [ 8431.335011] [drm:check_crtc_state] [CRTC:25]
Mar  8 10:51:28 ray-desktop kernel: [ 8431.335052] [drm:intel_crtc_cursor_set_obj] cursor off
Mar  8 11:09:01 ray-desktop CRON[4605]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -x /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean /var/lib/php5 $(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime))
Mar  8 11:17:01 ray-desktop CRON[4620]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Mar  8 11:33:31 ray-desktop kernel: [10959.173242] perf interrupt took too long (5003 > 5000), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 25000
Mar  8 11:39:01 ray-desktop CRON[4631]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -x /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean /var/lib/php5 $(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime))
Mar  8 12:09:01 ray-desktop CRON[4652]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -x /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean /var/lib/php5 $(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime))
Mar  8 12:17:01 ray-desktop CRON[4666]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Mar  8 12:39:01 ray-desktop CRON[4680]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -x /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean /var/lib/php5 $(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime))
Mar  8 12:50:36 ray-desktop rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="7.4.4" x-pid="660" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
```

Comment: `/var/logs/syslog` might not be the proper log.  Vishnu's [link](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/Freeze) lists useful instructions.  You also don't know whether your mouse and keyboard freeze, maybe your screen stop refresh but everything else is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try troubleshooting it with a little help from [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/Freeze).

Comment: Thanks, but those instructions are more than I can handle. Any noob ways to fix the error? any default software I can disable that might be causing this?

Comment: @VishnuNK 's guide in the comment is about boot repair, which doesn't seems to be related.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> would lead you to a full functional command line interface, you could login, do whatever you want.  And it's much more stable than the graphical part of Ubuntu.  <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> would takes you back to the graphical interface.

Although the GUI freezes, you can still use the command line interface. 
This enable you better diagnose your system.  You can [kill](https://askubuntu.com/questions/596830/kill-process-with-htop) problematic process.  [Restarting Xserver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1220/how-can-i-restart-x-server-from-the-command-line) can solve the problem temporarily.  In the worst case, you could safely [shutdown](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187071/how-do-i-restart-shutdown-from-a-terminal) your computer.