# Ubuntu froze. What to do (without rebooting)?

Tags: freeze

I always thought this is a simple question and should have a simple answer but it does not. (in Windows it is just Ctrl-Alt-Del)

My ubuntu froze and is furiously working  (I can hear the fan). I need to recover what I was doing, so I would like to not reboot.

Please don't post Ctrl-Alt-F1 as a solution. (I have see this so much.) First I don't know what does that do. Second it does nothing here. **nothing at all**. So it is not a solution.

Any way to open some kind of task controller? or to know the IP of the machine so that I can access it from outside?

Comment: They changed REISUB. You have to fully re-enable it. `sudo nano /etc/sysctl.d/10-magic-sysrq.conf`
Then change the number in line 26 from 176 to 244 i.e. kernel.sysrq = 244  Explanation of REISUB https://askubuntu.com/questions/926461/whats-the-difference-between-the-magic-reisub-reset-and-holding-down-the-power

Comment: Your work might be recoverable...but only if you are very lucky. The data you have provided so far suggests a greater probability that your work is not recoverable. A windows-like task manager is generally not needed on Linux desktops because the Linux kernel automatically terminates crashed or misbehaving applications for you. A Linux freeze is instead most often due to a kernel crash. However, we know nothing about your crash beyond your description, so maybe your freeze is different.

Comment: CTRL+ALT+F1 won't do anything on newer versions of Ubuntu. You would have to do CTRL+ALT+F4 where you can sign in with your username and password. Here's what it does: it opens a TTY screen (text only) so you can run commands in the terminal. Some commands that might help: `sudo htop` is like a task manager. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/596836/167115) for how to kill processes. To get back to your GUI screen, use CTRL+ALT+F2 or CTRL+ALT+F1

Comment: Outside access via ssh isn't going to give you more control than a TTY but you would need to access the TTY to get the local IP. Also, you would have to enable ssh before the problem. However, it might help to use `ifconfig` to show your local ip before the problem and also set up ssh access in case TTY is also unresponsive in the future.